# Nested Select Using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, orm

I would just like to know if derived queries can be handled by HQL? I have this bit of code right here and it kept on saying that it did not expect the '(' symbol right after the first FROM keyword. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
"SELECT new " + Distribution.class.getName() + " (adhoc, deployment, design, development, " +
"enhancement, requirements, testing) FROM (" +
    "SELECT AVG(week_adhoc) as adhoc, AVG(week_deployment) as deployment, AVG(week_design) as design," +
    "AVG(week_development) as development, AVG(week_enhancement) as enhancement, AVG(week_requirements) as requirements," +
    " AVG(week_testing) as testing, AVG(week_training) as training FROM " +
        "(SELECT dist.id, sum(dist.adhoc) as week_adhoc, sum(dist.deployment) as week_deployment," +
        "sum(dist.design) as week_design, sum(dist.development) as week_development," +
        "sum(dist.enhancement) as week_enhancement, sum(dist.requirements) as week_requirements," +
        "sum(dist.testing) as week_testing, sum(dist.training) as week_training from " + Distribution.class.getName() + " dist " +
        "where dist.week=1 and dist.month=1 and dist.year=2010 group by dist.id))";
```

Answer (score 0):

would you consider to implement using ICriteria instead of HQL?
it make the code more readable and programmable.